# Last Accessed Date and Last modified Date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get the last modified date of a table in PostgreSQL and also the timestamp when a table is last accessed using select statements in postgressql

Comment: No; PostgreSQL doesn't record such information.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58214/getting-last-modification-date-of-a-postgresql-database-table

Comment: is there a way we can add this functionality to postgresql so that we can record last accessed and last modified timestamps

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426656) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592620/)